# Evidence of what the big alien at the end of Men in Black looks like?

Tags: movie, character-identification, men-in-black

At the very end of *Men in Black* (the movie), we zoom out into space and then eventually it appears that our galaxy is just something inside a marble that some huge alien is playing with, but we never directly see what this alien looks like... or do we?

[image: A close up of the Earth "marble"; a reflection of the alien is seen on the surface]

If you pause on the Milky Way during zoom out, you can see a warped reflection of the alien. You can see the foot in the reflection raise up off the ground at the same time as the real alien's foot, so there is a bit of reference there, but other than that, it's hard to tell. There also appears to be an extra arm sticking out somewhere. You can also see a reflection off the marble that the alien fires the first marble at.

[image: The alien stands next to the Earth "marble" holding another in its hand,a reflection is seen on them]

However, I can't tell what on earth I am looking at. I get confused over the fact that the fingers don't really show up in the reflection as he reaches down. In fact, the reflection sort of recedes away from the marble. So the three yellow orb things I cannot tell if that is part of the head, or an arm, or what.  The other marble shows the alien as tall and hung-over in some way.

And then a final zoom out shows that there's *some* kind of head or blob on top of this thing.

[image: Over the "shoulder" shot of the alien who has flung the "Earth" marble, a warped reflection is seen in it]

Maybe someone else here has a better understand if reflection physics. What exactly do the reflections imply the alien looks like?

Answer (score 3):

The things we know from the scene are limited, so I did the same thing: snap the film and analyze.

Here are two shots of the alien's palm:

[image: The alien's reflection is seen in the Milky Way "marble"]

[image: The alien's reflection is seen in the Milky Way "marble" as its "arm" reaches down to pick it up]

From these, we can see the alien **stretch out a finger** and prepare to pick up the marble. We can also see a **reflection** in the marble of the alien moving its foot. Looking to the **upper left corner of the marble**，we can clearly see the shape of the alien's finger is changing，compared to the first photo you can see the alien's finger hasn't stretched out completely, so I guess this is the reflection of the back of the alien's hand.

From the **yellow things** you mention, I guess it is the eyes of the alien. We can also see a red triangular thing, which I guess is the part of the alien's nose. So the scene we can imagine is that the alien curls up its finger, bends over and watches the marble closely, then raises its body，moves its foot，stretches out the finger and picks up the marble.

If you look at the the alien's palm, compared to its finger (not the reflection), you can see some dark spots. That is because the alien's green skin is transparent: if you watch the scene of the alien pick up the marble, you can also see there is the artery inside the alien's arm，compared to the last photo you have posted (the alien picking up the two marbles). I guess the left part is the leg of the alien; you can stop the frame and slowly play, and you can see some yellow thing (an organ I guess) inside the alien's leg, that changes shape like jelly.

To sum up: we know the alien  has transparent skin，and we know what its finger, arm, foot, and head look like. I can't tell you what the alien look like in full. I thought the director would reveal the truth in *Men in Black 3*, but they didn't. The quality of the stills I took isn't very clear, perhaps we could see more detail if we took stills from the Blu-Ray release.