# How big is the alien shown at the end of the first Men In Black?

Tags: men-in-black

The end of Men In Black shows that our **Milky Way** is contained in a marble which is used by an alien to play a game.

Based on the known size of the Milky Way, can we make an estimate on the size of the alien?

see the pic below
[image: marble alien]

see the high quality clip

Comment: I don't think the "marble-alien" is intended literally. since it defies observation

Comment: I've edited your question to make it a little more readable and removed the 2nd question about the alien's appearance. You can ask about its appearance in a separate question if you like.

Comment: Since the "big alien" is [never shown in full](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124604/evidence-of-what-the-big-alien-at-the-end-of-men-in-black-looks-like?rq=1), any answer is going to be pure speculation.

Comment: *Based on the known size of the Milky Way, can we make an estimate on the size of the alien?*  - If you want to use the Milky Way in the screenshots to calculate the size of what's visible of the alien, sure, no reason why that can't be done. Just compare and multiply. What is it that prevents you from doing that?

Comment: @MishaR - What prevents it is that you don't see the entire alien. Which means that any answer is meaningless. The answer would be a range from the observed parts... up to infinity

Comment: @Valorum I get that. If you read my whole comment, I specifically say "calculate *what's visible* of the alien." That said, we have the ability to make guesses about the unknown based on the known. You may not like the idea of doing that, but it certainly is an option for the person asking the question.

Answer (score 4):

### 18.5 million light years

1. According to Wikipedia, marbles are commonly 1 cm in diameter.
2. According to Google, the average human is 5' 9".
3. So **the typical human is 175.26 times the height of a marble.**

The movie doesn't actually show the alien's head, so we can't be sure how tall it is. But if we assume that it has the same height ratio that humans have to their marbles, we can estimate the alien's height.

Our galaxy is roughly 105.7k light years in diameter. If we multiply that by 175.26, we get:

**18.5 million light years.**

Comment: Actually the entire galaxy is several times the diameter of the galactic disc, having a spherical halo of globular clusters and scattered stars, and a larger spherical halo of mysterious dark matter.  Which does make our galaxy more marble shaped.

Answer (score 3):

As the movie points out, size doesn't matter - e.g there is nothing preventing a whole galaxy from being inside a jewel-like container that can fit on the collar of a cat.  Therefore I posit that, within the movie universe, the question is essentially meaningless.

Comment: As Frank says in the movie about the galaxy on the cat collar - "Just because something's important, doesn't mean it's not very small." He clearly recognizes the concept of size. Size differences may not *matter* in the movie universe, but they certainly do *exist*. So a question about them may not be *useful*, but it isn't *meaningless*.